# typescript angular2: How to append an array to each object in an array?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I've a REST API which contains data in JSON format. I'm storing it in an array of objects. But I want to append a NEW EMPTY array to each object. I'm not able to do it.
Here is how my REST API looks like. I marked the new array which I want to add for each object in the comments.

```
       content = [
          {
            text: 'abc',
            options: [
                {
                  Id: 1,
                  Text: 'aaa'
                },
                {
                  Id: 2,
                  Text: 'bbb'
                },
                {
                  Id: 3,
                  Text: 'ccc'
                }],
// ARRAY[]

    },
          {
            text: 'def',
            options: [
                {
                  Id: 21,
                  Text: 'qwerty'
                },
                {
                  Id: 22,
                  Text: 'zxcv'
                },
                {
                  Id: 23,
                  Text: 'asdf'
                }],
    // ARRAY[]
          }
      }]
```

here is what I've tried.

```
public newarr:Array<any>;
this.httpservice.post('RESTUrl').subscribe(resp=>{
     this.contents = resp.data;
     this.contents.forEach((x:any)=>{
       x.push(this.newarr);
     });
     console.log("contents",this.contents);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to push an array onto an object, it should be `x.NewArray = this.newarr` or something.

Answer (score 1):

All you nee to do is to Add is simply using dot notation.

```
this.httpservice.post('RESTUrl').subscribe(resp=>{
   this.contents = resp.data;
   this.contents.forEach((x:any)=>{
     x.<value_name> = this.newarr;
   });
   console.log("contents",this.contents);
});
```

This way it will append your variable to the Array.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works.But is it the same for arrays as well ?

Comment: Yes you can add arrays as well

Comment: Is it the same way or do I need to write it like this : x.arr[]=this.newarr ?

Comment: you don't need to add `[]`. It will automatically take it. As all you are doing is appending Array to JSON array variable not Typescript variable.

Comment: Nope.. It didn't work for me when I put it like this :
var newarr:Array<any>=[];
 this.contents.forEach(x => {
           x.arr = newarr;
    }); 

But this worked : this.contents.forEach(x => {
        x.arr = new Array(x.choices.length);
    });

Comment: Glad you got the answer.